# Google Drive Infinite loop in resumable upload with an UNSTABLE network

Tags: google-drive-api

When I uploaded a file to the Google Drive using REST API, I found that every few seconds the HTTP connection would reset due to the unstable network (Obviously, Google's infrastructure is strong, but maybe you don't know what's COMMUNISM and what's GFW which we poor Chinese have to climb over in different own ways).

The problem is that Google's server will discard the data chunk she received if it's size less than 250kb (this value is estimated by my tests). Thus, if the network is disconnected before reach the value every time, we just upload the same chunk over and over again.

The only solution, I think, is to upload through a third server such as our program on GAE which never discard any data received.

BTW, Google Drive official PC client not works well in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google documentation confirms 256kb as the minimum chunk size. If a chunk fails, check the response header to see how much was received and resume from that point.

Comment: In fact, my problem is that if I upload a 2Mb file, first step I tell her I'll upload 2Mb this time, but, only 200Kb are sent the network is disconnected(TCP reset), so I make a new HTTP request to her, of course, I should ask her how many she received last time, then she tell me "The 200Kb I certainly received but it less than 256kb, I have discarded them, and now you start over the beginning". However, I can't reach the limit value before disconnect every time...

Understand? :(

Comment: Can you update your question with the actual http request and response headers that you are seeing.

Comment: Aha, the HTTP language is more understandable than my poor English, right? But I have used and tested resumable upload for a long time, and I don't entertain any hope at first. Anyway, thank you for let me know why Google discard the data < 256KB, and it's because the `n` must be multiples of 256KB. `HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete\r\n Content-Length: 0\r\n Range: n-2000000\r\n\r\n`